# how to change the text of delete button in a UITableCell on swap event

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have implemented the functionality to make delete button visible on swap and it also delets the cell by clicking on the button. but i just want to change the text of delete button from "DELETE" to "CANCEL"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implement the following in your [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return @"Cancel";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the UITableViewDelegate protocol method:

[`tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW26)